# Java I/O file program

Tags: java, file, input, output

In the following code, there's a basic I/O code that works with files:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("test.txt");

    try {

        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);
        output.println("Testing");
        output.println("123");
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.printf("ERROR: %s!\n", ex);
    }

    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( file );
        String message1  = input.nextLine();
        String message2  = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(message1);
        System.out.println(message2);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.printf("ERROR: %s!\n", ex);
    }}}}
```

Now when I try to run it, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:
>
> at Main.main(Main.java:11)

Any Idea to why this happens?

Comment: What compilation error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error.

There are one too many close curly braces.  Remove the very last close curly brace and you're good to go.